# Reading contact without using activity

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract

Im developping an library that read,list,add and search contacts in the phone.
I did it using Activity,cursor and managedQuery.
But to have a complete indepandant library i have to do it with out using an activity.
Is it possible to have a contact name per example just by this uri :"content://contacts/people/id" ? if yes can i have an example without using an activity ?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a more accurate answer if you would post some code, but if you would implement a method in your library which would retrieve contacts, then you will alyways have to have a Context instance as parameter of this method.

Try something like this:

```
public Contact readContacts(Context context)
{
  ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
  Cursor cursor = resolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
  ....
}
```

You would then call this method in an app which uses your library like this:

```
ContactHelper.readContacts(activity);
```

or like this:

```
ContactHelper.readContacts(getApplicationContext());
```

etc...

I assume you already have all required permissions, but don't forget to add this or you will not be able to read contacts:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
```

Here you can find more information about reading contacts with several code examples:
https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. in your example you still use activity i want to know if there is a way to not use it so i can make my library in a jar file ??

Comment: The way I posted it is the way you would implement it in a library. You  always need a Context for this but the solution to your problem is that your method needs a Context parameter, and everybody who uses your library would then supply a Context, for example an Activity, to your method.